# gt / ge operator doesn't work with where-object inside a powershell function

Tags: powershell

I am working on a script to fetch the inactive accounts for the last 21 days from Active Directory.

I know that there is a simple command for this:

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 21
```

But unfortunately this returns even those accounts whose `LastLogonDate` is older than the 21 days window. So I decided to filter the records based on the `LastLogonDate` property using the following commands:

```
$TimeSpan = 21
[DateTime]$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$TimeSpan) 
$DistinguishedName = "OU=TestOU,DC=Test,DC=local"
$InactiveAccounts = Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 21 -SearchBase $DistinguishedName | where-object {$_.LastLogonDate -ge $date}
return $InactiveAccounts
```

This works fine. But when I include this code inside a function and call that function with the required parameters it doesn't return anything. Whereas if I replace `ge` with `le` inside the function it works fine. Don't know why `gt` or `ge` is not working.

Comment: Do you want to get all accounts with `LastLogonDate` older or younger then 21 days?

Comment: I want all inactive accounts for the last 21 days so the lastlogondate should fall within the last 21 days timespan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Search-ADAccount` query will return all accounts with `LastLogonDate` older then 21 days. You want to get all accounts with `lastlogondate` within the last 21 days:

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 00.00:00:00 | Where {$_.LastLogonDate -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-21)}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin for the reply. You are right lastlogondate should be older than 21 days. So that means that Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 21.00.00.00 actually returns the right result.

But why does gt operator doesn't work inside a function?

Comment: gt ofcurse works inse a function. You should share a reproducable example with us.